# No autocompletion on module os

Tags: python, pycharm

Working in Pycharm, the beaviour of autocompletion has become strange.

After `import os`
There is one immediate autocomplete, suggesting `os` is found:

[image]

After adding a `.`, there is no autocompletion suggested:

[image]

But after entering a known function in `os`, e.g. `os.path`, autocompletion works again:
[image]

Am I being paranoid thinking that this has worked in the past???
I can add that for other modules, e.g. `shutil`, autocompletion works fine..

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the os module and restarting PyCharm?

Comment: @TD-Asker How do I reinstall the module? I restarted the computer, and it works again. I'm just waiting for it to happen again...

Comment: It will depends on your python package management system - conda/pip etc. It seems the 'ol turn it off and on again worked so hard to tell what's gone wrong.